# Cast char '-' minus why does it become zero "0" in sql server 2016?

Tags: sql-server

I have found a curious case (for me) the sql server 2016 engine when I execute this

```
select cast('-' as bit)
```

returns "0" zero
[image: In sql server 2016]

instead in sql server 2008 engine  the same query returns an error

> Messaggio 245, livello 16, stato 1, riga 1 Conversion failed when
>   converting the varchar value '-' to data type bit.

[image: In sql server 2008]

could someone give me an explanation?

Comment: have you tried experimenting with older compatibility levels?  Maybe it will be in the release notes for a new version somewhere.  I'm wondering if it is being taken to mean -0 or +0 (technically both being neither positive nor negative and ZERO), but both valid

Comment: I've had a scan of the patch notes/breaking changes ([2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017), [2005-2014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2014)) and couldn't spot anything. *Might* be due to the new cardinality estimator brought in with 2016?

Comment: You can convert +/- to int without any issue. Since bit is an integer type, it was probably brought in line with integer conversion. Still odd this hasn't been communicated.